# Is there a CPAN module for creating the CDF for a given list?

Tags: perl, statistics, cumulative-sum

It's not too difficult to implement, but it seems like [Cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is a very basic [`Statistics::Descriptive`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive) function, doesn't it?

It seems [`Statistics::Descriptive::Weighted`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive%3a%3aWeighted) has it, but using `Weighted` (with equal points to all data...) instead of the simpler `Statistics::Descriptive` seems to have a large overhead.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to post definition for CDF?

Comment: CDF is Cumulative Distribution Function. In this case, the OP is asking for the *empirical CDF* rather than the CDF of a given distribution.

Comment: If it's easy to implement (and indeed, it is), I'd suggest sending a patch to the author of Statistics::Descriptive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Statistics::KernelEstimation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Statistics%3a%3aKernelEstimation). I have not used it but it looks OK.

Using [Statistics::Descriptive::Weighted](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive%3a%3aWeighted), you can omit the weights and each point will be assigned a unit weight by default.

Answer (score 1):

A CPAN search came up with this: [`PDL::GSL::CDF`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDL-Stats/GSL/gsl_cdf.pd).  Its part of the [`PDL`](http://pdl.perl.org), the *Perl Data Language* (though this CDF module makes use of the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)).